# Vaadin popup should show and hide in the click event makes no appear popup

Tags: java, popup, vaadin, show-hide

Having a

```
  public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
             MyPopup popup = new MyPopup();
             getWindow().addWindow(popup);
             log.warn("Added POPUP");
    //lot of method calling here then
         getWindow().removeWindow(popup);
             log.warn("Removed Popup");
}
```

I would expect to show a popup window and after some milisecundom (after the expensive method calls) it should hide itself. The log says :

```
2014-02-19 15:26:51 WARN  xyzClass:82 - Added POPUP
2014-02-19 15:26:51 WARN  xyzClass:135 - Removed Popup
```

But the truth is that there is no popup showing here.

If i only show it, and not remove it later (the popup will show)
      public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                 MyPopup popup = new MyPopup();
                 getWindow().addWindow(popup);
                 log.warn("Added POPUP");
        //lot of method calling here then
                 log.warn("Removed Popup");
    }

My main reason for this i want to achieve a glasspanel/loading screen functionality @ Vaadin, and not had found better solution yet. Any solution/description why the popup not shown up i would appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Just do not have time to render it. You add it and immediately remove. 
Try this approach, for example:

```
private MyPopup popup;
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Thread workThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {         
            // some initialization here 
            getWindow().removeWindow(popup);
        }
    };
   workThread.start();             
   popup = new MyPopup();
   getWindow().addWindow(popup);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Interesting, i check it now, but you do the opposite you just remove it first! and then addWindow() can you fix your code? Or i maybe do not understand something.... (popup also declarate later)

Comment: Sorry Alexey, but i trully do not understand because you thread.start() and then said getWindow.addWindow(popup) so you first run your thread() and remove the window and after that you add it, it really seems me the opposite what i want to achive: I want to make a model popup (CSS it later to see like a glasspanel) and do some realy heavy calculation and then when i finished i want to close this model dialog (glasspanel)

Comment: anyway i upvote it because of your efforts but really would like to understand.

Comment: Access to Vaadin components from an external thread needs to be synchronized properly. The synchronization is missing form the example code.

Comment: This addon seems to the exactly what i need!
https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/refresher

Answer (score 1):

Depending on Vaadin version you can make use of [ICEPush](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/icepush) plugin (Vaadin 6) or built-in feature called [Server Push](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html) (Vaadin 7).

```
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    MyPopup popup = new MyPopup();
    getWindow().addWindow(popup);
    log.warn("Added POPUP");
    // start background thread with ICEPush or ServerPush
}

// Background thread in a separate class
// update UI accordingly when thread finished the job
    getWindow().removeWindow(popup);
    log.warn("Removed Popup");
```

Thanks to it you can move your time-consuming operations to another class thus decouple your business logic from the presentation layer. You can find examples of usage in the links above.

Comment: Thank you wypierpz, have atm no time to check this solution i will accept when i have time to check. Too bad there is no simplier solution for this simple problem : ( (upvoted)